# Does ERLANG ODBC support connection Pooling?

Tags: erlang, odbc, connection-pooling

Does Erlang/OTP's `odbc` module support connection pooling?

Searching for this directly leads to [very old documentation](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.3/pdf/odbc-1.0.8.pdf) which states explicitly that *"Connection pooling is not supported."*

The current Erlang `odbc` documentation ***do not*** mention how to configure it, or if it is available at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not using odbc at all but as I can see from [Erlang ODBC doc](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/odbc.pdf)

> Erlang ODBC application is designed using the version 3.0 of the
>   ODBC-standard

and according to this page [ODBC Connection pooling](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/conn_pool.html)

> As of release 2.0.0 of unixODBC the driver supports connection
>   pooling. This is a method to increase the connection speed of drivers,
>   but leaving connection's open and reusing them. This document
>   discusses how to implement connection pooling in unixODBC, and also
>   what you should be aware of before doing it.

So it means that Erlang ODBC support connection pooling

but I feel that you cant accept any options of pool directly from the Erlang application